How to hide object but remain shadows in Blender 4?
As I understand the interface of visibility has been changed, and now I just do not know how to hide the object but remain shadows from another items on it.


Hello, if you are using Cycles, it is still possible in the Object panel > Visibility > Ray VIsibility and disable Camera

As @moonboots said, what you are looking for are the Ray Visibility settings, they are not removed but are a Cycles feature (just like they were in older versions as well, that did not come with version 4), because Cycles is a raytracing engine ("ray" visibility settings).

@moonboots, I have checked: the switching off the camera in ray visibility does not remain the shadows

@GordonBrinkmann, I have checked: the switching off the camera in ray visibility does not remain the shadows

You may look for the Shadow Catcher option in Cycles in the Object panel > Visibility (there are some ways to do it in Eevee but I'm not sure that it's working well):

